# Where to store AWS keys in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-sdk

Is `database.yml` the right place to read the AWS keys from `bashrc`? `database.yml` sounds like a place only for database configs. Is there a more appropriate place where the AWS configs from bashrc could be read inside my Rails app?

Comment: could you clarify: Are you asking about where to store your AWS credentials securely, or where to load them into your application? @anuj-khandelwal has provided some great info in the former, and I've provided some info on the latter.

Answer (score 2):

**Rails 5.2 onwards**

Rails 5.2 has introduced the concept of [encrypted credentials](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2). Basically, from Rails 5.2 onwards, there is an encrypted credentials file that is generated on initializing the app in `config/credentials.yml.enc`. This file is encrypted, and hence, can be pushed to your source control tool. There is also a `master.key` file which is generated while initializing the app, which can be used to decrypt the credentials file, and make changes to it.

So, credentials for AWS could be added to it as:

```
aws:
  access_key_id: 123
  secret_access_key: 345
```

These keys could be accessed in your app as `Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key]`. Other sensitive config, like credentials to other external services that are being used, can also be added to this config. [Check out this blog by Marcelo Casiraghi](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336) for more details.

**Pre Rails 5.2**

There was no concept of a credentials system prior to Rails 5.2. There are a couple of ways in which you could try to come up with a solution to store your configuration.

A. You could create a `YAML` file for defining your config from scratch.

- Create a file called `my_config.yml` and place it in the `config` folder. Path: `config/my_config.yml`
- Add whatever configuration is required to the file, in `YAML` format (s described for AWS above)
- Make changes in `application.rb` to load this file during initialization as follows:

```
  APP_CONFIG = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.new(File.expand_path('../my_config.yml', __FILE__)).read).result)[Rails.env] rescue {}
```

- Using this approach, you will then be able to use `APP_CONFIG['aws']['access_key_id']` for the AWS configuration defined above. For this use case, it is strongly recommended to have separate configuration files for development and production environments. The production file should probably not be checked in to version control for security.

B. Another approach would be to use some gems for managing configurations like [railsconfig/config](https://github.com/railsconfig/config)

NOTE: To answer the bit about storing this configuration in `database.yml`, it is strongly recommended to not do so. `database.yml` is a configuration file for storing configuration related to databases. Separation of concerns really helps while scaling any application, and hence, it is recommended to place such configurations in a separate file, which can be independently maintained, without any reliance on the database config.

Comment: Thanks much! Could you show me an example how to store my aws key_id and key using YAML format please?

Comment: I tried this - and I am using the APP_CONFIG inside an asynchronous datajob and I get this error - `NameError uninitialized constant MyDataAsyncJob::APP_CONFIG`

Comment: The config will be of the same format as the one in this link: https://github.com/heroku/ruby-rails-sample/blob/master/config/secrets.yml
It will have to be divided into development and test for more flexibility as the file mentioned in the link is divided. Inside development, you would have the same section as the AWS config defined above in the answer

Comment: The uninitialized constant error seems a bit strange. Did you restart the app after creating the config? Also, what does your config look like?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. The standard place to configure things like AWS would be inside `config/initializers`. You can create a file in there called `aws.rb`.

```
app/
bin/
config/
|__ initializers/
    |__ aws.rb
```

and inside this file you can configure your AWS setup using the environment variables from your bashr

```rb
Aws.config.update({
   credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('your_access_key_id', 'your_secret_access_key')
})
```

Files inside this directory are executed on app start, so this configuration will be executed right when your app starts, before it starts handling requests.

It may also be useful to note that the [AWS SDK for Ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) will automatically search for specific environment variables to configure itself with. If that's what you're using, and if you have the following environment variables set up in your bashrc

- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

then you won't need any additional code in your Rails app to configure AWS. Check out more details [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby#configuration).